# Is there a new scope for Google MyBusiness API to replace plus.business.manage

Tags: google-api, google-my-business-api

The Google+ is being deprecated and in the email I got it says plus.business.manage will no longer be supported. From what I cant tell this scope is required to access Google MyBusiness API. Is there a new scope to be used or will this API no longer be supported?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/gmb-api/page/1/thread-id/16534) on Jan 30, 2019, Andrew H from Google says the `plus.business.manage` scope should not be affected.

I've included the response below.

> On January 29, we sent an email regarding projects that will be impacted by the Google+ API shutdown. The email stated that projects requesting the "plus.business.manage" scope would be affected. The team is actively investigating why this email was triggered.
>
> No action is needed by you at this time.

**UPDATE**

In a followup email they sent Mar 4, 2019, there is a sentence "See the full outline of scope behavior here," which links to the [documented replacement scope](https://developers.google.com/+/scopes-shutdown#manage_a_business_listing) for "plus.business.manage," which is simply "business.manage."